# Adding MVC4 Display Modes Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In `Global.asax`, I want to add a number of display modes dynamically, based on a string array I have, thus:

```
foreach (string displayModeId in myDisplayModeIds)
{
    modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode(displayModeId)
        {
            ContextCondition = context =>
                context.Request["DisplayMode"] == displayModeId
        }
    );
}
```

Of course this doesn't work, because `displayModeId` needs to be a constant within the scope of the `ContextCondition`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture it in a closure so that it doesn't run away from you in the loop:

```
foreach (string displayModeId in myDisplayModeIds)
{
    string dmId = displayModeId;
    modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode(displayModeId)
    {
        ContextCondition = context => context.Request["DisplayMode"] == dmId
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks.  I'd already tried Clone(), but only on `displayModeId`.